# How to assign the alert message textfield input value to the button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton, uialertview

How to assign the alert message textfield input value to the button?

In the below code, I am assigning value to textfield but requirement is assign value to button instead of textfeild through alert message help me to solve the problem in iPhone.

```
-(IBAction)alertmessage{
     [self setingValue];       
}

 -(void)setingValue{
    myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter year" message:@"alert message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [myAlert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"entervalue"];     
    alertTextField=[myAlert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    alertTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
    alertTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    alertTextField.keyboardAppearance=UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSString *buttonTitle=[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {
       yearSelection.text= alertTextField.text;
    }
}
```

if i enter keyboard value from alert textfield as input type that has to assign or appear on the button.

Comment: **Please make sure that you format your code after you post it.**

Comment: what value do you want to assign to the button..? your question is not exactly clear..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)setingValue{

  myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter year" message:@"alert message"  
  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
  alertTextField=[UITextfiled alloc]initwithFrame:CGRectFrame:(5,25,200,35)]; //set the frame as you need.
  alertTextField.Placeholder=@"Enter Value";
  alertTextField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
  alertTextField.clearsOnBeginEditing=YES;
  alertTextField.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
  alertTextField.keyboardAppearance=UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
  [myAlert addSubview:alertTextFiedl];
  [alertTextField release];
  [myAlert show];
  [myAlert release];
}
```